# Vue: блокировка кнопки при неактивном чекбоксе

Tags: vue.js

Есть чекбокс и кнопка. Как на Vue блокировать кнопку при не чекнутом чекбоксе?

Answer (score 1):

Остается добавить в data стейт, который будет хранить в себе состояние чекбокса:

```
data() {
  return {
    check: false
  }
},
```

И связать компоненты: для чекбокса есть v-model, а чтобы блокировать кнопку достаточно использовать атрибут disabled:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="check">
<button :disabled="!check">Отправить</button>
```